# how can I send to parameter from adapter to Activity

Tags: android

how can I send to parameter from adapter when I Click TextView  "tvlist" to  Activity "SelectAddressActivity", in SelectAddressActivity i have two EditText which i want be filled with parameters from adapters

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    Typeface quicksandRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");


    final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    AddressList al= objects.get(position);

    final TextView tvlist = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.id_TextView);
    tvlist.setTypeface(quicksandRegular);
    tvlist.setText(al.get_addresse());


    tvlist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String content = tvlist.getText().toString();

        }
    });
```

Activity

```
public class SelectAddressActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<AddressList> addressList ; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_address);


        final ListView addressListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addressListView);


        final SelectAddressAdapter adapter = new SelectAddressAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addressList);      
        addressListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using an interface, here I have created OnClickInAdapter interface and it defined in the adapter class.
Put the below code in your adapter,

```
    OnClickInAdapter onClickInAdapter;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Typeface quicksandRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
    final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    AddressList al = objects.get(position);
    final TextView tvlist = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id_TextView);
    tvlist.setTypeface(quicksandRegular);
    tvlist.setText(al.get_addresse());
    tvlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String content = tvlist.getText().toString();
            try {
                onClickInAdapter = (OnClickInAdapter) context;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(contxt.toString()
                        + " must implement OnClickInAdapter");
            }
            onClickInAdapter.onClickInAdapter(content);
        }
    });
}

public interface OnClickInAdapter {
    public void onClickInAdapter(String content);
}
```

And now the activity should implement this interface so that when OnClick method in adapter is called, ultimately the activity's method which is onCLickInAdapter() is called, put the below code in your activity,

```
public class SelectAddressActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.OnClickInAdapter{

@Override
public void onClickInAdapter(String content) {
    // you can fill the editText here
}
}
```

Let me know if it works and mark as an answer so that it would be useful to others...

Answer (score 3):

You have to send `onclick` on row ,like below

```
 row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddressList al= objects.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SelectAddressActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", objects.getyourvariable());

            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi
this is adapter 
first parameter activity     
 - activity cannot be resolved to a variable

Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SelectAddressActivity.class);

Comment: you have to send parameter from adapter to another activity..right?

Answer (score 2):

1. make interface;

   ```
   public interface AsyncResponse {
       void processFinish(Object output);
   }
   ```
2. and add activity

   implements AsyncResponse
3. in Activity you have to implement processFinish(Object output)...
4. in Adapter, add member variable

   public AsyncResponse delegate = null;
5. in setOnClickListener, add this code:

   delegate.processFinish(YOUR PASS DATA);